# Tautological vector bundle over $G_1(\mathbb{R^2})$ isomorphic to the Möbius bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, grassmannian

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space, and let $G_k(V)$ be the
>   Grassmannian of $k$-dimensional subspaces of $V$. Let $T$ be the
>   disjoint union of all these $k$-dimensional subspaces and let
>   $\pi:T\rightarrow G_k(V)$ be the natural map sending each point $x \in S$ to $S$. Then $T$ has a unique smooth manifold structure making
>   it into a smooth rank-$k$ vector bundle over $G_k(V)$, with $\pi$ as a
>   projection and with the vector space structure on each fiber inherited
>   from $V$. $T$ is called the **tautological vector bundle over**
>   $G_k(V).$

What I want to prove is that tautological vector bundle over $G_1(\mathbb{R^2})$ is isomorphic to the Möbius bundle.

(This is a problem from *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* by Lee and Möbius bundle is defined as in Lee's book, [page 105.](http://books.google.com/books?id=eqfgZtjQceYC&pg=PA105#v=onepage&q&f=false) Also I took the definition of the tautological vector bundle over $G_k(V)$ from Lee's book as well.)

Comment: What ways do you know of showing two bundles are isomorphic?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Writing a smooth bundle isomorphism between them. I do not know if it is enough to show that the transition functions are the same.

Comment: Can you see that $G_1(\mathbb R^2) \cong \mathbb RP^1 \cong \mathbb S^1$? It's only a step from there, to construct an isomorphism explicitly.

Comment: @Sam: Now I see what I need to show. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Sam pointed out $G_1(\mathbb{R^2}) \cong \mathbb{RP^1} \cong \mathbb{S^1}$. Now,  writing a smooth bundle isomorphism is not so hard.