# Möbius bundle as a tautological bundle

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds

I was trying to solve the exact same problem that was discussed in this question: [Tautological vector bundle over $G_1(\mathbb{R^2})$ isomorphic to the Möbius bundle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90069/tautological-vector-bundle-over-g-1-mathbbr2-isomorphic-to-the-mobius-bun)

I came up with the step to identify one-dimensional projective space with the one-sphere by myself, but that didn't make it any clearer. Even when I draw a picture I cannot see how an element of the tautological bundle should "twist around" the one-sphere (I seem to end up with the trivial bundle), let alone can I write down an explicit bundle isomorphism. Can anyone make the identifications when one passes from projective space to the circle clear? It seems that my problem lies there.

Comment: Possibly useful answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617343/bbbrp1-bundle-isomorphic-to-the-moebius-bundle/617406#617406) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447567/flag-manifold-to-complex-projective-line/448316#448316). (The latter contains a diagram.)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Take a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and rotate it by 180 degrees. The line is now the same, but what can you say about what happens to the orientation?

Remember that the Grassmannian $G_1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ parameterizes lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but does not concern itself with a basis of that line, i.e. an orientation of the line.